# testing with mocks and doubles being treated like methods

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, stubs

I have introduced mocks and and stubs into my testing and all was going well. I have hit a bit of a wall because since changing the code to test further i am getting the following error in rspec but i cannot understand why it is coming up with errors. When i was just testing it should hit below 16 everything was fine but when i introduced the test for it should hit above 16 i get the following errors.

```
undefined method `double' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::Hand::PlayAsDealer:Class (NoMethodError)
```

The piece of code in question is below:

```
describe "#play_as_dealer" do 
        it "should hit below 16" do 
            deck = double(:deck, :cards => [Card.new(:clubs, 4), Card.new(:diamonds, 4), Card.new(:clubs, 2), Card.new(:hearts, 6)])
            hand = Hand.new
            2.times { hand.hit!(deck) }
            hand.play_as_dealer(deck)
            expect(hand.value).to eq(16)
        end

        it "should hit above 16"
            deck = double(:deck, :cards => [Card.new(:clubs, 4), Card.new(:diamonds, 4)])
            hand = Hand.new
            2.times { hand.hit!(deck) }
            hand.play_as_dealer(deck)
            expect(hand.value).to eq(17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second test was missing a do and end-problem now resolved!

```
it "should hit above 16" do 
            deck = double(:deck, :cards => [Card.new(:clubs, 4), Card.new(:diamonds, 4)])
            hand = Hand.new
            2.times { hand.hit!(deck) }
            hand.play_as_dealer(deck)
            expect(hand.value).to eq(17)
        end
```